# Horizontal Forms instead of vertical

Tags: html, css

Language: PHP, HTML

Hi, I am having an issue with making some buttons that represent rooms.
Each button is labelled with a room number and I am trying to get the buttons to be side by side.

```
        foreach($row1 as $row2)
        {
            echo "<form method='post' action='ss room details.php'>";
            echo "<button>".$row2."</button>";
            echo "<input type=hidden name=roomNum value=".$row2.">";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "</td>";
```

The buttons are listed vertically and make a new line for each button. How do I display it horizontally?

Thanks!

Comment: this question has nothing to do with PHP. it's HTML/CSS question

Answer (score 0):

You want to `float: left;` (CSS) on each one.

However, floating acts kind of strange sometimes, so you'll definitely want to do some Googling to get a good idea of how it works.

So, to quickly show you with inline CSS, modifying your original code:

```
foreach($row1 as $row2)
{
    echo "<form method='post' action='ss room details.php'>";
    echo "<button style=\"float: left;\">".$row2."</button>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=roomNum value=".$row2.">";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "</td>";
```

**EDIT:** It's never a good idea to use inline CSS, though, so putting the CSS in your spreadsheet is a much better idea:

```
button {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Correct. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/dfesp/ - but NEVER EVER code the CSS in the `style` attribute for crying out loud!! :)

Comment: I was just giving a simple example! :P But, yeah, definitely never use inline CSS. I was just doing it for simplicity.

Comment: I totally understand, but if you're going to teach someone how to do something, you should teach them the correct way, no?

Answer (score 0):

The buttons wouldn't probably end up next to each other horizontally, except for the fact that you're including each one in a separate `form` element.  In your css, you can float the `form` left:

```
form {
float: left;
}
```

You could also float the buttons, too -- make sure to try it in different browsers.  Wouldn't hurt to include a CSS reset template too.

Comment: Don't forget that semicolon! :P

Comment: @compeek you can omit it in this case

Comment: @Knu, there's not really a good reason to omit it, though. But yeah, you're right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
float:left
```

like @compeek has mention or you can use break tags like this:

```
foreach($row1 as $row2)
        {
            echo "<form method='post' action='ss room details.php'>";
            echo "<button>".$row2."<br/>";
            echo "<input type=hidden name=roomNum value=".$row2."><br/>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "";
```

Comment: Break tags would still make them be on separate lines, though. That's the point of a line break.

Comment: Jeeze I am retarded I read it the other way around.. goo dyslexia

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use `display: inline`. This will make the form and the button behave like normal elements in the text flow. Do a line break `<br>` where necessary.

```
form { display: inline }  
button { display: inline }
```

Comment: The problem with that is that then you can't really use margins or padding (or at least not as easily). `inline-block` combines the best of both worlds, but it doesn't work consistently in all browsers.